# Why is the word for silver in Torah the same word for money?

Tags: hebrew, tanach, money

Is there a reason why the Hebrew word for silver is the same word for money in Hebrew?

Comment: Have you seen a quarter? Same thing.

Comment: No. It's not the same name stricto sensu. But it's also used because at the old time of the etalon monay was made by in silver

Comment: Same in French - argent.

Comment: @kouty same idea

Comment: @Dr Shmuel it very frequent in all language and called metonymy

Comment: @Dr. Shmuel can you please remove the [on hold] label from my question. Thank you.

Comment: I only have the ability to contribute to put things on hold but not viceversa

Comment: @msh210 can you please remove the [on hold] label from my question. Thank you.

Comment: @AlBerko if the question is about language in the Torah, can you identify a place where in the Torah the word כסף means money?

Comment: @DoubleAA "וְכִי־יִגֹּף שׁוֹר־אִישׁ אֶת־שׁוֹר רֵעֵהוּ וָמֵת וּמָכְרוּ אֶת־הַשּׁוֹר הַחַי וְחָצוּ אֶת־כַּסְפּוֹ וְגַם אֶת־הַמֵּת יֶחֱצוּן׃ " Another אַךְ אִם־יוֹם אוֹ יוֹמַיִם יַעֲמֹד לֹא יֻקַּם כִּי כַסְפּוֹ הוּא׃

Comment: @AlBerko does that not mean "divide its value in silver"?

Comment: @DoubleAA ..."since he is the other’s property", property=money? I'm not here to argue. It seems that the Pshat IS money. Or "וּלְהָשִׁיב כַּסְפֵּיהֶם אִישׁ אֶל־שַׂקּוֹ "

Comment: @AlBerko that one is unambiguously silver. Put the silver they brought back in their bags.

Comment: @DoubleAA English says money. What better Pshat can I find? Why do you assume that all the money was exclusively silver in the first place? It could surely stem from it but very quickly it became a term. Just like jeeps

Comment: @AlBerko surely the word eventually came to mean money generally. I'm just not convinced that happened before Genesis was written.

Comment: (re your comment addressed to me) I don't see any difference in the question between when I put it on hold and now. If I maintained it should be on hold then, then presumably I still do. Asking me to remove that status is not the way to go. Verifying why I imposed it is better, if you don't know; better still is editing the question so it doesn't deserve to be on hold.

Comment: @DrShmuel you can vote to reopen too

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not correct based on 
[This article](https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/10386-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-kesef). See the 2nd paragraph.

Excerpts:

> In this week’s parshah (Breishit 31:30), Lavan says to Yakov: nichsof
>   nichsafta le-veit avicha—you longed for your father’s house. The two
>   words nichsof and nichsafta are both from the root KSF, the same room
>   as KSF, money.
>
> Most likely, the verb KSF originally meant “to become pale with
>   longing.” And the noun KSF did not originally mean “money.” Rather, it
>   meant “silver.” Why did silver get this name? Because of its
>   whiteness, it became known as the “pale metal.” So the commonality
>   between “silver” and “longing” is the whiteness/paleness aspect, and
>   not anything else. I followed Ernest Klein: “A Comprehensive
>   Etymological Dictionary of the Hebrew Language,” p. 282
>
> Another widely used etymology book, “Etymological Dictionary of
>   Biblical Hebrew” by Matityahu Clark, takes a slightly different
>   approach. It views the fundamental meaning of KSF as “yearn, desire”
>   and then views silver as a “desired asset.” But why should only silver
>   be desired, why not gold? And why are not all precious metals called
>   kesef? The better approach is the one taken by Klein, which focuses on
>   the paleness aspect.

Later on, the word became to mean "money", but that's not its original meaning. Languages change for various reasons, and I suspect that since silver was originally used as a means to conduct business transactions, it was thought of as "currency" until paper notes and other metals were substituted.

Comment: How does this answer the question about  silver and money?

Comment: Analogy, maybe - Note that while the language used for redeeming a 1st born son mentions *kesef* (silver), currently, there is no requirement to use silver shekel weight.